# If $G$ isn't abelian and $|G|=p^{3}$ then $Z(G)=G'$

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ a finite group and $G' \subseteq G$ the smallest normal subgroup of $G$ such that $G/G'$ is abelian. Prove that if $G$ isn't abelian and $|G|=p^{3}$ then $Z(G)=G'$

My attempt:

If $G$ is not abelian, $Z(G) \neq G$. If $|G| = p^{3}$, then by Sylow there are subgroups of orders $p$ and $p^{2}$

I know the center of a p-group is also non-trivial. But would that imply that the smallest normal group is $Z(G)$? Why?

Comment: "...the smallest **non-trivial** normal subgroup is the center"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose $G$ is a nonabelian group of order $p^3$ for $p$ prime.

Since $G$ is a $p$-group, $Z(G) > 1$; since $G$ is not abelian $Z(G) < G$. So $|Z(G)| = p$ or $p^2$. If $|Z(G)| = p^2$, then $G/Z(G)$ would be a cyclic group of order $p$ and thus implying $G$ is abelian. So we must have $|Z(G)| = p$; thus $G/Z(G)$ is a group of order $p^2$ and hence abelian (One should verify that for prime $p$ all groups of order $p^2$ are abelian.). Then $G' \subseteq Z(G)$ since $G'$ is smallest normal subgroup of $G$ whose quotient is abelian. Since $G$ is nonabelian, $G' > 1$ and this forces $G' = Z(G)$.

Comment: Comment: Since $|Z(G)| = p$, we have that $G/Z(G)$ is an abelian group of order $p^2$ as noted above. A group of order $p^2$ is either $C_{p^2}$ and $C_p\times C_p$ up to isomorphism; since $G$ is nonabelian, it follows that $G/Z(G) \cong C_p \times C_p$. So by the correspondence theorem, we know the subgroup lattice of $G$ above $Z(G)$ is the same lattice as $C_p \times C_p$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: (1) If $G$ is non-abelian then $G/Z(G)$ is non-cyclic. (2) Every group of order $p^2$ is abelian.

You already noted that the center should be non-trivial for your group.

Answer (score 1):

if $|Z(G)|=p^3$ then $G$ is a abelian group.It is contradiction.

if $|Z(G)|=p^2$ then $[G:Z(G)]=p$ thus $\frac{G}{Z(G)}$ is cyclic and  $G$ is a abelian group.It is contradiction.

Therefore  $|Z(G)|=p$

Comment: Why $|Z(G)|$ can't be $1$?

Comment: $G$ is a $p-$ group ,so it has non-trivial center.

Answer (score 1):

Every group of order $p^2$ is abelian and the center is always normal. The hypothesis implies that $|Z(G)|=p$. Its quotient is therefore abelian and so $G'\subseteq Z(G)$. The other containment follows from minimality.